# Fail2ban jail config not working. IP still showing in logs

Tags: nginx, fail2ban

I am fighting with trying to ban IPs by user agent. It's showing as banned, yet it's still showing up in my logs.

In my jail.local

```
[megaindex-crawler-spam]
enabled = true
filter = megaindex-crawler-spam
logpath = /var/log/nginx/*access.log
maxretry = 1
findtime = 10
bantime = 86400
```

In /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/megaindex-crawler-spam.conf

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^\d{4} <HOST> .* MegaIndex.ru.*


Status for the jail: megaindex-crawler-spam
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed: 39195
|  `- File list:    /var/log/nginx/**************.access.log 
/var/log/nginx/access.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 12
   |- Total banned: 17
   `- Banned IP list:   78.46.128.204 46.4.64.197 144.76.60.98 
176.9.137.17 144.76.27.118 5.9.6.51 5.9.32.222 176.9.16.209 <-- THIS ONE
78.46.161.81 5.9.98.178 5.9.83.211 176.9.41.28
```

One of the logs. The IP address is shown to be banned, but it's still coming:

```
8222 176.9.16.209 - - [26/Oct/2018:10:41:07 -0500] **************.com 
"GET /contact_us.php HTTP/1.1" 200 13389 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; 
MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)" "-"
```

I am trying to make a "catch all" by using the User-Agent in my jail. It works with iptables, but this bot has so many IP addresses that I would prefer to ban it by its user agent.

Comment: What is your `banaction`?

Comment: I'm very new to fail2ban. I'm going to assume if you're asking about it that I need it. I'll look into what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could ban this user-agent with nginx:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* (megaindex-crawler-spam) ) {
        return 403;
    }
```

Comment: Where would I place that if statement?

Comment: Turns out I can't do it that way because we have 4,000+ separate config files that are generated for different domains. I'm gonna have to use fail2ban.